# Docker version used by AWS ECS Fargate 1.3.0

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

What version of Docker does Amazon ECS 1.3.0 when using Fargate? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/platform_versions.html says 1.4.0 uses Containerd instead of Docker but it doesn't specify any versions of either.